# Only allow one active instance of a Chrome js extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to run my extension only once when Chrome is opened - my extension will notify me when something on network will be found. Here is the problem - when I open many tabs in a browser I will get multiple notifications and I want them to appear only once. So my question is - how to run extension only once when Chrome is opened?

I found this topic: [Only allow one active instance of a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754536/only-allow-one-active-instance-of-a-chrome-extension), but it doesn't cover my needs, because I don't use a HTML file. I use only JS and `chrome.notifications`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [chrome.runtime.onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) event, which is fired when a  profile that has the extension installed is first started up:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
    chrome.notifications.create({...});
});
```

Sometimes if you close Chrome, it could still be running in the background. As per [this blog post](https://www.h3xed.com/programming/run-something-when-chrome-first-starts-chrome-extension-development), you could listen on the [chrome.windows.onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onCreated) event instead, and check the window count:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows) {
        if (windows.length == 1) {
            chrome.notifications.create({...});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that's it :) thx, I've just found it - notification about your answer didn't come to my email and i wanted to answer my question myself :)

Comment: @cinkciarzzpolski Glad you got it. If you are happy that this sufficiently answers your question, please accept the answer so other's are aware.